# A problem of calculating sum in probability

Tags: probability

Let $p$ be the probability of head when toss a coin once, $X$ denote the number of heads and $Y$ denotes the number of tails.

Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

As usual, I work on

1. $P(X=a, Y=b)=\dbinom{a+b}{a}p^{a}(1-p)^b$
2. $P(X=a)=\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\dbinom{a+b}ap^a(1-p)^b\quad$ (so does $P(Y=b)$.)

But how to claim clearly that $P(X=a,Y=b)\not=P(X=a)P(Y=b)$? I don't know how to work on the sum...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use $$1=1^\infty=(1-p+p)^\infty = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^Np^n(1-p)^{N-n}\dbinom{N}{n}$$
Be aware of the infinity, but maybe you can use the substitution  $b=n$ and  $a=N-n$

Comment: But now, one of my $a$ or $b$ is fixed, so how to apply the limit?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $X,Y$ are dependent you only need a specific counter-example to break the independence rule. Assume we have $n$ coin tosses.

$$P(X=0\cap Y=0) = 0 \qquad\text{(since this event is impossible.)}$$

However,

$$P(X=0)P(Y=0) = (1-p)^np^n \neq 0\qquad\text{(assuming $0\lt p \lt 1$.)}$$

Therefore, $X,Y$ are dependent random variables.

Comment: What if I want to check the general case? (Not only X=0, Y=0)